# Encrypting string in Rails using AES-128 plus cipher mode CBC with PKCS5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I am trying to implement a feature on my site for a 3rd party app that is requesting I encrypt a string using the following:

`site expects the email to be encrypted using the AES algorithm with your 128 bit secret key. The cipher mode is CBC with PKCS5 padding. The initialization vector is 16 bytes of 00.`

1. Using your secret key, generate a 128-bit secret key using the first 16 bytes.
2. Read the bytes of the plain-text email encoded in "UTF-8".
3. Encrypt the email using the AES algorithm and your 128 bit key. Be sure to use CBC mode and PKCS5
   padding.
4. Convert the encrypted bytes to hex string.

I created a method and started to try to figure this out, but have not gotten too far.

```
  def elink
    @base = ENV['API_TOKEN'][0..15]
    OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.hexdigest((@base).to_s)
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** From reading API info, it looks like `Cipher` in Ruby is deprecated and I should indeed use `Digest`. I also found some info on [OpenSSL PKSC5](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-Encryption) but I don't really understand how to piece this together for the task at hand.

Also have looked around SO and found some QAs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506547/aes-java-encoding-ruby-decoding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938430/aes-equivalent-in-ruby-openssl?rq=1), but again... over my head for this example.

Comment: You should try and learn a bit about cryptography before continuing. Just trying at random - as you are doing with the digest - is not going to end well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new 'AES-128-CBC'`, then set your key and an IV consisting of 16 zero bytes. This should already use [PKCS#5/PKCS#7 compatible padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172).

A digest is not an encryption method, and it is certainly not compatible with AES-128.